# Table header left alignment with Siunitx package

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

I am trying to produce a table with the Siunitx package, and to make the text in the header to be left aligned and to start where the numbers begin (see the red line in the attached screenshot). Does anyone know how to do it?
[image]

MWE:

```
%:Class
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%:begin
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\caption{Descriptive Statistics}
\begin{tabular}{l|s[table-text-alignment = left]*{4}{|S[table-number-alignment = left]}}
 &         {N}&      {Mean}&      {S.D.}&       {Min}&       {Max}\\
A&      95,703&       0.522&       0.500&           0&           1\\
B&      94,826&       0.062&       0.241&           0&           1\\
C&      94,301&       3.080&       1.435&           1&           6\\
D&      90,049&       0.332&       0.471&           0&           1\\
E&      94,860&       0.065&       0.960&       -5.27&        3.49\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the `s` second column type, as opposed to `S`?

Comment: I don't quite know. But without the small "s" it does not put the thousand's comma separator. The problem is also at the big "S" columns.

Comment: To get proper thousands-separators (with commas functioning as the separators), do by all means use the `S` column type. Just set the options `group-separator={,}` and `group-minimum-digits=4`, and make sure to *delete* the commas in the input numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, if I've well understood, with some æsthetic suggestions:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=6pt, labelfont=sc, textfont=it}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand\myShead[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\parbox{\widthof{0.500}}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\sisetup{table-format = 1.3, table-number-alignment=center, group-separator={,}}
\caption{Descriptive Statistics}
\begin{tabular}{l!{\vrule width1pt}S[table-format =5.0]*{2}{|S}|S[table-format =-1.2]|S}
 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{N}& \myShead{Mean}& \myShead{S.D} & \myShead{\phantom{$-\!$}Min}& \myShead{Max}\\
A& 95703 & 0.522& 0.500& 0& 1\\
B& 94826& 0.062& 0.241& 0& 1\\
C& 94301& 3.080& 1.435& 1& 6\\
D& 90049& 0.332& 0.471& 0& 1\\
E& 94860& 0.065& 0.960& -5.27& 3.49\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thanks