# Table header left alignment with Siunitx package (long column name)

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

I am trying to produce a table with the Siunitx package, and to make the text in the header to be left aligned and to start where the numbers begin (see the red line in the attached screenshot). 
[image]
I got an answer for a similar question (see [Original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547907/table-header-left-alignment-with-siunitx-package)), but in the original question the column name was short.

MWE:

```
%:Class
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%:begin
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\caption{Descriptive Statistics}
\begin{tabular}{l|s[table-text-alignment = left]*{4}{|S[table-number-alignment = left]}}
 &         {Observations}&      {Mean}&      {S.D.}&       {Min}&       {Max}\\
A&      95,703&       0.522&       0.500&           0&           1\\
B&      94,826&       0.062&       0.241&           0&           1\\
C&      94,301&       3.080&       1.435&           1&           6\\
D&      90,049&       0.332&       0.471&           0&           1\\
E&      94,860&       0.065&       0.960&       -5.27&        3.49\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do the commas in the first data column denote? Thousands-separators? Something else?

Comment: Separately, what's the reason for using the `s` column type for the first data column. Should this maybe be `S`?

Comment: @Mico: In the comments to one of their previous questions, OP commented on their use of `s` instead of `S`:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547907/table-header-left-alignment-with-siunitx-package#comment1383981_547907

Comment: @leandriis - Thanks for this link. I've left a comment below the linked comment, pointing out that it is *not* necessary or, frankly, even advisable to use the `s` column type in this way. Instead, the OP should do what you did in *your* answer shown below: employ the `S` column type, either set the option `input-ignore={,}` or just delete the commas in the affected cells, and set the option `group-minimum-digits=4` if need be.

Comment: Indeed, the s column was left in the MWE by mistake. The commas in the first data column are also redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the appropriate `siunitx` options and under the assumption that the `,` in the first column are thousands-separators:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%:begin
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\sisetup{input-ignore={,}, 
         input-decimal-markers = {.}, 
         group-separator={,}, 
         table-text-alignment = left}
\caption{Descriptive Statistics}
\begin{tabular}{l|S*{2}{|S[table-format=1.3]}|S[table-format=-1.2]|S[table-format=1.2]}
 & {Observations}&      {Mean} &      {S.D.} &       {Min} &       {Max} \\
A&      95,703   &       0.522 &       0.500 &           0 &           1 \\
B&      94,826   &       0.062 &       0.241 &           0 &           1 \\
C&      94,301   &       3.080 &       1.435 &           1 &           6 \\
D&      90,049   &       0.332 &       0.471 &           0 &           1 \\
E&      94,860   &       0.065 &       0.960 &       -5.27 &        3.49 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I might also abbreviate `Observations` to `Obs.` :-)

Comment: @leandriis Could you the same thing if all column names were long? for example if all column names were "Observations"?