# Table header left alignment with Siunitx package (long column name) - continued

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

I am trying to produce a table with the Siunitx package, and to make the text in the header to be left aligned and to start where the numbers begin (see the red line in the attached screenshot).

I have already got an answer for a similar question (see [original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548451/table-header-le)), but in the original question only the first column name was long.

MWE:

```
%:Class
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%:begin
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\sisetup{input-ignore={,}, 
         input-decimal-markers = {.}, 
         group-separator={,}, 
         table-text-alignment = left}
\caption{Descriptive Statistics}
\begin{tabular}{l|S[table-format=1.2]*{2}S[table-format=2.1]}
&{Coefficient}&{Standard deviation}&{Effect on actual score} \\\hline
a&.47&54.5&25.6\\
b&.51&49.2&25.1\\
c&.45&43.7&19.7\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]ft-alignment-with-siunitx-package-long-column-name?noredirect=1#comment1385299_548451

Comment: For what you like to have, you not need `S` columns  but ordinary `l`: `\begin{tabular}{l| l l}`.

Comment: but what if the length of digits is varying and not symmetric -- 149.2 in the centre instead of just 49.2